# FREEMARKER: avoid escaping HTML chars

Tags: freemarker, html-escape-characters

Having a problem with freemarker output...

```
                [#assign optionsHTML = ""]                    
                [#list data as item]
                    [#assign optionsHTML = optionsHTML + '<option value="' + item.value +'>'+ item.label + '</option>' /]
                [/#list]
```

so, if I do

```
<select>
${iptionsHTML}
</select>
```

the output from otions get html entities instead of actual html.... so

```
&lt;option value=&quot .....
```

even if I do

```
            [#assign optionsHTML = ""]                    
            [#list data as item]
                [#noescape]
                [#assign optionsHTML = optionsHTML + '<option value="' + item.value +'>'+ item.label + '</option>' /]
                [/#noescape]
            [/#list]
```

tried even

```
<select>
${iptionsHTML?html}
</select>
```

but's even worse :(

Comment: Have you tried putting noescape around the ouput? [#noescape]${optionsHTML}[/#noescape]

Comment: Note that `[#noescape]` is now deprecated [freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_escape.html](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_escape.html). See the new kids in town since Freemaker **2.3.24**: [freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after trying stuff, I don't know what I've done wrong before, but clean, this way is working

```
[#assign optionsHTML = ""]                    
[#list data as item]
   [#assign optionsHTML = optionsHTML + '<option value="' + item.value +'>'+ item.label + '</option>' /]
[/#list]



<select>
   [#noescape]
   ${optionsHTML}
   [/#noescape]
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting `#noescape` around `#assign` has no effect. Automatic escaping only applies to `${...}`-s that are embedded *directly* into the static text (the HTML). So there's no escaping to disable inside that `#assign`.

`?html` is used to escape a string "manually". Like in your example you could write `optionsHTML = optionsHTML + '<option value="${item.value?html}>${item.label?html}</option>'`, because you know that the value will be output non-auto-escaped later, and the `${...}`-s inside the string literal aren't escaped automatically.

However, the best would be if you can organize your code so that things that generate HTML don't construct the HTML inside variables and then print the variable, but print the HTML directly into the output. That's what FTL is designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Like ddekany said, write something like this:

```
<select>
  [#list data as item]
    <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
  [/#list]
</select>
```

Comment: yes, I did, but than I had to use 2 lists....probably didn't mention that part... the only reason why I am doing it with building HTML string var is to avoid iterating through the list twice (once for outputting the select options, another time to get the label, which is determined by checking the selected option... I just needed to simplify this example so I could get the answer for the bit I actually needed

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem in string with special chars.
In this example I have checknumber = "6547&6548"
which caused problem before using this #escape

the best and simple way to handle this as following code

```
<#escape x as x?html>${deposit.checkNumber}</#escape>
```