# Output string as html in freemarker

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

So we are storing html in out data model. I need to output this into a freemarker template:

example:

```
[#assign value = model.value!]
${value}

value = '<p>This is <a href='somelink'>Some link</a></p>'
```

I have tried [#noescape] but it throws an error saying there is no escape block. see [FREEMARKER: avoid escaping HTML chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123397/freemarker-avoid-escaping-html-chars). This solution did not work for me.

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[#noescape]` or `<#noescape>` is only valid when used inside an `[#escape]` tag. Your data is probably stored with the HTML encoded. You need to get the backend to un-encode the html.

Otherwise you'll need to do something like...

```
${value?replace("&gt;", ">")?replace("&lt;", "<")}
```

But that isn't a good approach because it won't catch all the encoded values and shouldn't be done in the view layer.

Comment: This is exactly what we found to be the case. Thanks!